# Why might an External IP change on a Google Cloud Platform VM instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I realized that the external IP of my VM instance changed to an IP that I don't know. Also, next to the external IP it says "(ephemeral)".

What could cause this to change?  How do I prevent that in the future?

Comment: As far as fixing the immediate problem, change the DNS entry?  You probably want to set the TTL to something low while you're at it so you can recover easily the next time (until you fix the underlying issue).

Answer (score 6):

Instances are automatically given an IP address, which is subject to change if the server is restarted, crashes, etc. If you want it to have a fixed IP, you need to [provision one](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address).

Chances are you've lost the original IP - it'll be back into the pool of millions of IP addresses for someone else's instance to use. You'll need to change the IP in your DNS records to the new static one.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [ceejayoz's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/885787/37475), it should be noted that you can [promote an ephemeral IP to a static IP without it changing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#promote_ephemeral_ip).